# Remove rake test when using RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm using RSpec in my Rails App, but when doing `rake -T` I'm still getting the default `test` rake tasks:

```
rake spec             # Run all specs in spec directory (excluding plugin specs) / Run RSpec cod...
rake spec:controllers # Run the code examples in spec/controllers
rake spec:models      # Run the code examples in spec/models
rake spec:requests    # Run the code examples in spec/requests
rake spec:routing     # Run the code examples in spec/routing
rake stats            # Report code statistics (KLOCs, etc) from the application
rake test             # Runs test:units, test:functionals, test:integration together
rake test:all         # Run tests quickly by merging all types and not resetting db
rake test:all:db      # Run tests quickly, but also reset db
```

Is this normal? Can/should I remove them somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Goto to your `config/application.rb` file & replace

```
require 'rails/all'
```

with this:

```
# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

Notice, now we no longer are loading test_unit, so its rake tasks won't get included.